# Masterpage Feature Stapling not applied to Blog (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, master-page, my-site, blog, feature-stapling

I've created a feature staple for my sites to apply a particular master page. It appears to work for all the subsites/pages in */personal/[userid]/* except for the blog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Can you apply your theme via the UI? 
Is your feature activated/deployed on your blog? 
The .master needs to be in the blog web in under `_catalogs/masterpage`.

Also make sure you configured your FeatureStapling correct - Blog is not the same site template as the other sites.

Here's a example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Team Sites -->
  <!--<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="STS#0" />-->

  <!-- Enterprise Search Center -->
  <!--<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SRCHCEN#0" />-->

  <!-- Basic Search Center -->
  <!--<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SRCHCENTERLITE#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SRCHCENTERLITE#1" />-->

  <!-- My Site Host -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSMSITEHOST#0" />

  <!-- My Sites -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSMSITE#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSPERS#3" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSPERS#4" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="SPSPERS#5" />

  <!-- Blogs -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FeatureID_Placeholder" TemplateName="BLOG#0" />

</Elements>
```